# Display a bottom message on click checkbox

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to display a bottom message on listing product when someone click on one or several checkbox. But I don't see nothing inside my page.

Code:

```
 <style>
        .box{
            color: #eee;
            padding: 20px;
            display: none;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        .green{ background: #228B22; }
        label{ margin-right: 15px; }
    </style>

// loop to display the products with the checkbox

                while($Qlisting->fetch()) {
...
    echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="green"> green</label>';
...
                }

<div class="green" style="display:none;">Your message</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        $("." + inputValue).toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What relevance in your `<style>` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggle() is used to interval between display:inline and display:none;
You are currently trying to toggle elements with no matching classes to your selector. `('.' + inputValue)`

Create the the message you want to display inside a div with the same class as the corresponding checkbox value.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        $("." + inputValue).toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="green"> green</label>

<div class="green" style="display:none;">Your message</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works (inside the lopp) but not like expected for me. Sorry it's my false. I updated the code above to allow you what I try to make. The message must appear one time if I click on checkbox, not inside the loop.